# Leading slash for url in .html files while serving static files in Golang?

Tags: html, css, go, go-gin

This seems to be a small problem, and I believe a solution is out there somewhere, but I don't know how to find a suitable keywords combination for searching.
So, say I have an index.html file, which have this code:

```
<link href="assets/css/template_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then, if I open the index.html file through the browser locally would automatically search for the template_style.css in the designated location, which should be obvious.
The thing is, if I then serve this file with a web framework, I have to change it to

```
<link href="/assets/css/template_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Notice the leading slash before assets. I tried 2 framework, Gin and Beego, so I think this is a common bevaiour? However, because of this, opening the index.html file locally would NOT load the template_style.css.
So what is the best way to make the index.html openable both locally and serving through server.

Comment: Browsers interpret URLs relative to the current page's URL.  Use an absolute path as in the second example to reference an asset from any page on the site.  The first example only works for pages at the root of the site.

Comment: I would also recommend always serving your html through an HTTP server even when doing local development. Your computer's file system is not really designed as a web development platform.

Comment: I am just serving static web page, so I don't really want to make things complicated. I just want to make sure the web show literally the same page as I see it while open locally.